# About a problem with spring-quartz beans configuration problem. One of them is not running

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

i have two spring quartz scheduler classes named SpringQrtzScheduler and EthQuartzScheduler.

I am watching in [log file](https://pastebin.com/VbhnXWFh) that only one is being triggered and executed, EthQuartzScheduler, and I do not understand it what only one is running, because, if you see in logs:

```
web - 2019-07-23 14:14:16,176 [main] INFO  c.a.d.s.SpringQrtzScheduler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4d6ae522 - SpringQrtzScheduler POSTCONSTRUCT...
web - 2019-07-23 14:14:16,218 [main] INFO  c.a.d.s.EthQuartzScheduler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ec94f3a8 - EthQuartzScheduler POSTCONSTRUCT...
```

Spring is executing @PostConstruct initialization phase of both quartz schedulers, but only EthQuartzScheduler is being scheduled to run every 5 seconds. Why SpringQrtzScheduler is not being scheduled?

```
web - 2019-07-23 14:14:16,238 [main] INFO  c.a.d.s.EthQuartzScheduler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ec94f3a8 - ETH Quartz scheduler set up!
web - 2019-07-23 14:14:16,247 [main] INFO  c.a.d.s.EthQuartzScheduler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ec94f3a8 - Configuring trigger to fire EthQuartzScheduler every 5 seconds
web - 2019-07-23 14:14:16,247 [main] INFO  c.a.d.s.EthQuartzScheduler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ec94f3a8 - ETH-Qrtz_Trigger TRIGGERED!
web - 2019-07-23 14:14:16,303 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
```

This is the [code](https://pastebin.com/AaCXznyK) of SpringQrtzScheduler and this is the [code](https://pastebin.com/v93d3429) of EthQuartzScheduler.

I think that it is a code problem, if you think I have to share pom.xml and quartz.properties, please, let me know.

EDIT

It looks like the code does not permit both concurrent jobs, isn't? because, if I disable one of the jobs, the other one runs fine, but I need both jobs working...

EDIT

If I add @DisallowConcurrentExecution, same behavior. Only one of the jobs is running.

[quartz job code and auto wired dependency](https://pastebin.com/HpMG6aYA)

thank you very much.

Comment: Have you considered disabling the ethquartzscheduler so all you have left is the springqrtzscheduler?

Comment: I did it and happened that SpringQrtzScheduler is running, the other one. It is curious, isn't?